# Has the <fx:deploy ...> ant task changed in Java9?

Tags: java, ant, java-9

Since switching to Java 9, I can no longer get my application packaged using the  task. There are at least 2 issues:

1. The basedir attribute of  seems no longer to be supported
2. My .iss file, used to create the Windows executable, is longer be found

I cannot find any documentation to suggest there are changes. My ant task is:

```
  <target name="package" depends="dist, createIss" description="Creates a signed installer for the self-contained xLauncher">
    <!-- We add . to the classspath so we can use the xLauncher.iss file generated by the createIss target -->
    <taskdef resource  = "com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
             uri       = "javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
             classpath = "${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar:."/>

    <fx:deploy width          = "600"
               height         = "400"
               outdir         = "${launcher.dist.package}"
               outfile        = "DELETE_ME"
               offlineAllowed = "false"
               nativeBundles  = "exe"
               verbose        = "false">

        <fx:application name    = "${launcher.app.name}"
                        version = "${launcher.app.version}"/>

        <fx:info title="xLauncher" vendor="${launcher.vendor}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${launcher.dist.home}" includes="xLauncher.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>

        <!-- Set any JVM arguments, to be used when the .exe is run -->
        <fx:platform basedir="${baseDir}">
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
        </fx:platform>

        <fx:bundleArgument arg="installdirChooser" value="true"/>
    </fx:deploy>
  </target>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

The output with the basedir attribute is:

> C:\SfnDevelopment\trunk\sfnLauncher\build.xml:248: fx:platform doesn't
>   support the "basedir" attribute
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:396)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:344)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChild(UnknownElement.java:580)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.java:349)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.configure(UnknownElement.java:201)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109) Caused by: The  type doesn't
>   support the "basedir" attribute.
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper.setAttribute(IntrospectionHelper.java:402)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:388)
>       ... 16 more

The output from ant with -verbose, without the basedir attribute, is:

> parsing buildfile
>   jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-9/lib/ant-javafx.jar!/com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml
>   with URI =
>   jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk-9/lib/ant-javafx.jar!/com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml
>   from a zip file   [macrodef] creating macro 
>   javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:init-ant  Running [C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\java.exe, -version]  Running [C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe, /?]    Detected [C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe] version [5]  At least one type of
>   shortcut is required. Enabling menu shortcut.  "Adding modules:
>   [java.rmi, java.sql, javafx.web, jdk.charsets, java.logging,
>   java.xml.crypto, java.xml, jdk.xml.dom, jdk.jfr, java.datatransfer,
>   jdk.packager.services, jdk.httpserver, javafx.base, jdk.net,
>   java.desktop, java.naming, javafx.controls, java.prefs,
>   java.security.sasl, jdk.naming.rmi, jdk.zipfs, java.base,
>   jdk.crypto.ec, jdk.management.agent, java.management, java.sql.rowset,
>   javafx.swing, jdk.jsobject, jdk.sctp, java.smartcardio,
>   jdk.unsupported, jdk.jdwp.agent, jdk.scripting.nashorn,
>   java.instrument, java.security.jgss, jdk.management, java.compiler,
>   javafx.graphics, jdk.security.auth, java.scripting, javafx.fxml,
>   jdk.dynalink, javafx.media, jdk.accessibility, java.management.rmi,
>   jdk.naming.dns, jdk.security.jgss, jdk.localedata] to runtime image." 
>   Running [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javapackager.exe,
>   --icon-swap, C:\Users\MICKFR~1.LIG\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler13933937517016729133\windows\xLauncher.ico,
>   C:\Users\MICKFR~1.LIG\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler13933937517016729133\images\win-exe.image\xLauncher\xLauncher.exe]
>   Running [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javapackager.exe,
>   --version-swap, C:\Users\MICKFR~1.LIG\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler13933937517016729133\windows\xLauncher.properties,
>   C:\Users\MICKFR~1.LIG\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler13933937517016729133\images\win-exe.image\xLauncher\xLauncher.exe]
>   Generating EXE for installer to:
>   C:\XDevelopment\trunk\xLauncher\package-dist  Running [C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe,
>   /oC:\XDevelopment\trunk\xLauncher\package-dist,
>   C:\Users\MICKFR~1.LIG\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler13933937517016729133\images\win-exe.image\xLauncher.iss]
>   in
>   C:\Users\MICKFR~1.LIG\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler13933937517016729133\images\win-exe.image
>   Installer (.exe) saved to:
>   C:\XDevelopment\trunk\xLauncher\package-dist

Comment: can you provide a log of running `ant package`?

Comment: Output added in original post (not that helpful, I think!)

Comment: What do you specify using `basedir="${baseDir}`? Its value and purpose I mean to ask. I don't see any change in its usage in Java 8 vs 9.

Comment: I don't see `basedir` being supported in JavaFX 8 ant tasks as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_task_reference.html#CIAEEFCJ -- what was it supposed to do?

Comment: Ah - maybe it was deprecated in 8 and removed in 9? It used to allow the specification of the JDK to be bundled with the app - by default it's the "current version". My main issue, though, is not being able to use a customised .iss file with InnoSetup to produce the Windows installer - it just doesn't appear to find it.

Comment: Furthermore, setting verbose="true" in the <fx:deploy> now has no effect. What I'm doing is as documented in section 6.3.3.1 of [self-contained-packaging](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#BCGICFDB)

Comment: I thought this might be a regression of [bug 8095828](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8095828) but the workaround given there does not help

Comment: Same problem for me,  i look into class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.Platform of JDK9, the method setBasedir no longer  exist.